# How do I create a triangular stencil with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut

I started out working on an OpenGL program written in C that loads a 3D model from the user's filesystem with ASSIMP and renders it into the center of a window created with GLUT. So far I've gotten that basic rendering step working just fine. Now I want to render that same model into an OpenGL stencil in the shape of a triangle, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I have included an image representing the desired effect:
[image: desired effect image]
To elaborate, I want to make a triangle shaped stencil over my model as demonstrated below:
[image: elaborating diagram]
My code is pretty basic, all I do is enable `GL_STENCIL_TEST`, setup the stencil function, draw my triangle, and then draw the model.

```
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
// Fill stencil buffer with 0's
glClearStencil(0);
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
// Write 1's into stencil buffer where the hole will be
glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, ~0);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
// Draw the triangle hole shape
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex2f(-0.3f, -0.3f);
glVertex2f(0.f, 0.3f);
glVertex2f(0.3f, -0.3f);
glEnd();
// Draw scene, keeping fragments with 1's in the stencil buffer
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, ~0);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
// Renders the model
drawTheModel();
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

My GLUT display mode is as follows:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
```

When I run the above code, all I get is an empty window. I've read the documentation and checked loads of examples, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I downloaded and compiled [this stencil example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Stencil_buffer) and added my triangle stencil. My triangle stencil seemingly draws into the depth buffer - investigating. How my stencil looks on the example:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you change `glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, ~0);` to `glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, ~0);` does it render the model normally?

Comment: Yeah, `glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, ~0);` shows the model normally. :-\

Comment: Have you tried rendering the triangle to the colour buffer, to make sure it's in the shape and location you expect?

Comment: Yup! Looks like your average, everyday triangle when I render it separately.

Comment: I don't see you clearing the depth buffer. Do have depth test active? Have you tried setting GL_REPLACE for all arguments in the first glStencilOp?

Comment: No cigar on both counts. I disable the depth buffer with `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);`, so disabling the depth test would be redundant. Using all `GL_REPLACE` didn't change anything.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't glDepthMask only disable writing to the depth buffer? If you want to turn depth test completely off I think you need to call glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

Comment: Interesting. I'll try this tomorrow.